# LXD container disk and block I/O limits. EDIT: Its a zfs pool limit

Tags: zfs, lxd, container

There is a container running on my system and it is is giving me the (28: No space left on device) error message.

I tried to troubleshoot the problem and I see why it probably is complaining:

```
bas@Viky:~$ lxc exec Emby-container -- df -h /
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
zfspool1/containers/Emby-container  4.0G  4.0G  128K 100% /
```

So I tried to change the disk size:

```
bas@Viky:~$ lxc config device set Emby-container root size 20GB
```

After that, no change:

```
bas@Viky:~$ lxc exec Emby-container -- df -h /
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
zfspool1/containers/Emby-container  4.0G  4.0G     0 100% /
```

But when I look at the config, it shows that it changed the size:

```
bas@Viky:~$ lxc config show --expanded Emby-container
name: Emby-container
profiles:
- default
config:
  volatile.base_image: f4c4c60a6b752a381288ae72a1689a9da00f8e03b732c8d1b8a8fcd1a8890800
  volatile.eth0.hwaddr: 00:16:3e:b2:25:fe
  volatile.last_state.idmap: '[{"Isuid":true,"Isgid":false,"Hostid":165536,"Nsid":0,"Maprange":65536},{"Isuid":false,"Isgid":true,"Hostid":165536,"Nsid":0,"Maprange":65536}]'
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: br0
    type: nic
  root:
    path: /
    size: 20GB
    type: disk
  videos:
    path: /home/emby/Videos
    source: /home/bas/Videos/
    type: disk
ephemeral: false
```

Also restarting the container did not work.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**
@adonis
You are right, the zfspool is not bigger than 4.97GB.

```
NAME       SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
zfspool1  4,97G  4,81G   158M         -    70%    96%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

I'll go and figure out how I can enlarge the zfspool.

---

**EDIT2:**
I seem to be unable to find a way to make the pool bigger.
What I can make out of the content of the web is that it is imposible. That I should make a new pool, copy the content of the old pool to it, tell LXD/the container to use the new one and destroy the old pool.
Is there an easy way here or is this above the only way?

---

Thanks,
Bas

Comment: Maybe you are restricted by the size of your pool. Try `sudo zpool list zfspool1` to check whether this is the case.

Comment: You are right adonis!

Comment: Is this a file-backed zpool? If it is, then data integrity isn't probably a big concern (or you have other ways to guarantee it) and you can easily add more vdevs to it.